# discord.py bot isn't answering when mentioned from phone app

Tags: python, discord.py

I made recently a discord bot for small server with friends. It is designed to answer when mentioned, depending on user asking. But the problem is, when someone mention bot from a phone app, bot is just not responding. What could be the problem?
Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '=')
reaction = ""

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message): 
    if str(message.author) in ["USER#ID"]:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)

@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    mention = f'<@!{BOT-DEV-ID}>'
    if mention in message.content:
        if str(message.author) in ["user1#id"]:
            await message.channel.send("Answer1")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Answer2")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that if you have multiple functions with the same name, it will only ever call on the last one. In your case, you have two `on_message` functions. The use of listeners is right, you just need to tell it what to listen for, and call the function something else. As your code is now, it would never add "" since that function is defined first and overwritten when bot reaches the 2nd `on_message` function.

The `message` object contains a lot of information that we can use. [Link to docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)

`message.mentions` gives a list of all users that have been mentioned in the message.

```py
@bot.listen("on_message")   # Call the function something else, but make it listen to "on_message" events
async def function1(message): 
    reaction = ""
    if str(message.author.id) in ["user_id"]:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)


@bot.listen("on_message")
async def function2(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions: # Checks if bot is in list of mentioned users
        if str(message.author.id) in ["user_id"]: # message.author != message.author.id
            await message.channel.send("Answer1")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Answer2")
```

If you don't want the bot to react if multiple users are mentioned, you can add this first:

```
if len(message.mentions)==1:
```

A good tip during debugging is to use `print()` So that you can see in the terminal what your bot is actually working with.
if you `print(message.author)` you will see `username#discriminator`, not `user_id`